# How to determine variables between two lines of input?

Tags: java, string, file, loops

In my project, I have to iterate through files using Java.  The idea of it is processing genome data and outputting it to a new file.

Here is an example from a couple lines of data we have to go through:

```
cure for cancer protein
ATGCCACTATGGTAG
captain picard hair growth protein
ATgCCAACATGgATGCCcGATAtGGATTgA
bogus protein
CCATt-AATgATCa-CAGTt
```

I am struggling on how one would logically decipher between the name for the region ("cure for cancer protein") and the following sequence of characters.  I can get the file to display all info easily, but I need to process the sequence of characters differently than the region name and I can't figure out how to logically determine if the line is a region name or a sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on your example, the names appear on even line numbers, and the proteins appear on odd line numbers. The names start with a lowercase, not the sequences. The names contain spaces, not the sequences.

Comment: Ah, the spaces.  I didn't think of that.  Thank you!!

Comment: Either you find a rigid way of distinguishing them (even f it requires reworking some files by hand, and imposing stricter formatting rules for future files), or you're forced to use heuristics. Frankly, using such a loosely defined file format for a system dealing with "cure for cancer proteins" is scary. Why not use a well-defined file format, like JSON, XML, or even simpler conventions like starting a name by `#`?

Comment: You can split the file into lines

Answer (score 0):

What about using RegExp? I think you can define is your line contains `[ATGC-]` only.